# Htaccess Laravel - Removing Public Folder URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I already upload my project to my host

The link is **examplesite.com/Hiflyer/public/index**

I want all my route their look like this.

**examplesite.com/index**

**examplesite.com/news**

This is my **HTACCESS:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>


    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]


</IfModule>
```

The question is how to configure it?

Comment: It should work by default. Did you deploy on shared hosting?

Comment: no. in xampp only.. @JamalAbdulNasir

Comment: there are two ways of doing it. create a virtual host or run 'php artisan serve' in the root directory of the project. And then access your project http://locahost:8000

Comment: my server is public, how can i view the localhost:8000 in other pc?

Comment: so u deployed your project? are you using shared hosting?

Comment: no, we're using amazon cloud server, and we are running xampp as our host server

Comment: so u must have set the root for your URL. In this case the root will be your public folder not the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Perform 2 simple steps and you could run your laravel project without /public folder.
1.) Move the .htaccess file to the main directory from public folder without any changes.
2.) And do the same with index.php.

Rest .htaccess file working has following content.

```
RewriteEngine On


#----------------------------------------------
# | this code use for remove public directory |
#----------------------------------------------




RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.ico|\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.eot|\.svg|\.ttf|\.woff|\.woff2|\.otf|\.pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(login|uploads|assets|css|js|images|ca|favicons|fonts|)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]


RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

And index.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Comment: when i solved the problem. all the assets cant access.

Comment: make sure you have given 775 permission to /public folder.